# string.Join For comma-separated values

Tags: c#, string, checkboxlist

With the help of `string.join`, we can split a comma-separated list of values.

```
string.join(",", array)
```

Can I do the same for a `CheckboxList` data source? 
I have a `DataValueField` for this and need a comma-separated values without doing iteration.

Comment: Something's gonna have to do the iteration; might as well be you.

Comment: You mean `string.Join(",", (IEnumerable<object>)checkboxlist.DataSource)`?

Comment: Why do you need do it without iteration? `string.join` iterates too, has to!.

Comment: @Roger, #Hemal, String.Join iterates and takes care of the last-one different issue, well worth using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in Fx4 there is an overload of `String.Join()` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`.

But it depends on what the DataSource property actually points to, roughly:

```
string line = string.Join(",",  ComboBox1.DataSource.Select(x => x.Name) );
```

You may need a different lambda, and some typecasting of DataSource.

Edit:

```
var data = (List<MyClass>) (ComboBox1.DataSource);
string line = string.Join(",",  data.Select(x => x.Name) );
```

Comment: I have a class and the return type of the datasource is List<MyClass>. So how should i do with it ?

Comment: The OP says it's a `List<MyClass>`, but there is really no point in casting to it, cast to `IEnumerable<MyClass>` will obviously suffice

Comment: Yes, but if you know for sure it's a `List<>` you should always check.

Answer (score 0):

Could make use of the little known CommaDelimitedStringCollection to make life easier ...

```
using System.Configuration;

var strList = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
strList.AddRange(ComboBox1.DataSource.Select(x => x.Name.ToString()));
var commaListStr = strList.ToString();
```

More info here ... http://www.idevforfun.com/index.php/2010/02/07/comma-delimited-lists/

Answer (score 0):

The string.Join() solutions obviously work, if you feel like LINQ-ing you can also Aggregate the comma separated values string:

```
var list = (List<MyClass>)(ComboBox1.DataSource);
string commaSeparatedValues = list.Select(v => v.Name).Aggregate((current, next) => string.Concat(current, ",", next));
```

Just be aware of possible performance hits when handling large amounts of strings like this.